# use of Present Perfect without time reference

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, perfect-aspect

I have a doubt about the use of present perfect.
If I want to say that something happened in the past but I don't want to express when it happened or it's not important, can I use present perfect?
For example" I have donated 2000€ to charity" (I donated 2000€ in the past but the focus is on the action not when it happened)
other example: " I have created this tool" (focus on the result of the creation).

Comment: Short answer, yes. That is one of its uses.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't given any context. Are you writing this on a cv? Are you answering a question during an informal conversation?

Comment: I read this phrases on the slides of my university course where there isn’t a specific scenario

Comment: You can imagine then like single phrase